# Proving inequalities hold for all values

Tags: inequality

Show that the inequality

$$\frac st + \frac tr + \frac rs \ge 3$$

holds for all positive $r,s$ and $t$.

Comment: Use AM GM inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) :

Since $s/t,t/r,r/s\gt 0$,

$$\frac st+\frac tr+\frac rs\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac st\cdot \frac tr\cdot\frac rs}=3.$$